# how to allow users customize calculation of fields?

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

I'm working a payroll system in Laravel, right now the value of some payroll fields is calculated during the 'creating' and 'updating' of the Payroll Model using our default formulars.

However, I want to add a feature to allow users to customize the formulars of the calculation.

How do I go about that?

Comment: If they are just fields, could you expose them as variables with system defaults?

Comment: Never let users run arbitrary code on your site. That's a recipe for a data breach. Instead, you should implement different formulas in your code, and let users _choose_ which one they want to use.

Comment: can you please go a little more into details? @ChrisHaas

Comment: Well, for instance. if your payroll equation is `$hours * $rate` and you have `$rate` fixed at `20`, you could offer up an admin interface to change the rate. This might be system-wide, client-wide, project-wide or per-person, but you'd have to make that determination.